# trying to create an inputbox that will have text

Tags: css

I am trying to create a css that will give me an input box but also some text on top of it. I was able to create the input box but I am not sure how to add in the css that the lable associated with that input field shows up on the top.
here is the example to what I have

http://jsfiddle.net/McdhR/2/

**edit**

```
<div class="header">


<div class="workspaceDetails">




<input name="t" id="hj" class="input"/> 
<input name="t" id="hj" class="input"/> 
<input name="t" id="hj" class="input"/>     




</div>


 .header {
        background-color:#f5f5f5;
        height:50px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

.input
    {
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }​
```

​

Comment: In your previous question (5 minutes) ago I asked you to put your code here. This applies to all questions and not just that one.

Comment: You are a 1.5K rep user, who asked 348 question. You're a member for **2 years**. ***YOU SHOULD KNOW HOW TO ASK A QUESTION BY NOW!*** -1.

Comment: sorry I didnt see that. I will put the code here

Comment: That isn't valid HTML. There is no closing `div` and you have used multiple elements with the same `id`.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/trickeedickee/McdhR/3/

The `placeholder` attribute is new with HTML5 and will work in limited browsers. The `value` attribute will work in all browsers.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I want the text to show on top of the input boxes. As the label